# Can I use a plain text JWT with Google Wallet?

Tags: android-pay

I'm trying to create a 'donation' button using Google Wallet. The user should be able to type in an amount into a text box and click a 'donate' button.

It was possible to do this without any server side code with Google Checkout in the past, but with Google Wallet, I need to provide a server side service to compute the JSON Web Token (JWT) for use with the Google Wallet API.

In an attempt to skip the need for a server side service, I attempted to create a plain text JWT, as per the [JWT specification](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#Plaintext). Google Wallet did not like it. It complained about missing text where the JWS signature would be, even though I set the JOSE header to indicate there was no encryption.

1. Does Google Wallet support a plain text JWT?
2. If Google Wallet does support a plain text JWT, what can I specify as JWS signature, give that Google Wallet does not like the empty string as specified in the JWT spec?
3. Even if it was possible, am I overlooking some potential security issue generating a plain text JWT on the client? Again, these are for donations, whose amounts are specified by the client anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skipping the "Donations" use case (you'll have to check with official Google Support for that).

> I set the JOSE header to indicate there was no encryption.

Nope, not supported....

> [**2 (Server): Generate a JSON Web Token (JWT)**](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#1)
>
> *The Google Wallet for Digital Goods API uses JSON Web Tokens—or JWTs, pronounced like the English word jot—to represent each item for purchase in JSON format. **To securely verify the origin of these JWTs**, you'll encode and sign them with a secret key before passing them to the client.*
>
> *Because you sign the JWT using a secret key (the Seller Secret), you must generate the JWT using server-side code....*

Hth...